# Parallelizing Radix Sort OpenMP C

Tags: c, openmp

I have the following radix sort algorithm that I am trying to parallelize using OpenMP:

```
void radixSortEdgesBySource(struct Edge *edges_sorted, struct Edge *edges, int numVertices, int numEdges) {

   int i, j, d, c;
   int key;
   int pos;
   int maximum = 0;

   int *vertex_cnt = (int*)malloc(numVertices*sizeof(int)); 

   maximum = edges[0].src;


   for (c = 0; c < numEdges; c++)
   {
       if (edges[c].src > maximum)
       {
           maximum  = edges[c].src;
       }
   }

   while(maximum != 0)
   {
       maximum /= 10;
       ++d;
   }


   for (j = 1; j < d; j++)
   {
       #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4) 
       for(i = 0; i < numVertices; ++i) 
           vertex_cnt[i] = 0;
   }
       #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
       for(i = 0; i < numEdges; ++i) 
       {
           key = edges[i].src;
           vertex_cnt[key]++;      
       }

       for(i = 1; i < numVertices; ++i) {
           vertex_cnt[i] += vertex_cnt[i - 1];
       }

       #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
       for (i = numEdges - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
           key = edges[i].src;
           pos = vertex_cnt[key] - 1;
           edges_sorted[pos] = edges[i];
           vertex_cnt[key]--;
       }
   }
  free(vertex_cnt);
}
```

I want to know if the way I have used `#pragma omp` is correct? Because I am not really seeing any considerable change in the speed of execution.

And also how would I go about parallelizing the loop block that does the cumulative summing?

Comment: Read about "parallel scan".

Comment: what is the typical value of numVertices and numEdges  ?
BTW you should probably keep the same parallel context instead of having several; and did you simply try to find where is the hotspot of the sequential code (no measurment => waste of time optimizing)?

Comment: They are user defined.

Comment: What do you mean by same parallel context? I'm a little new to openmp so I'm kinda a noob

Comment: Looks like you're introducing a lot of race conditions and other bugs by parallelizing those loops. Read up on shared vs private variables in openmp to start.

Comment: Critical regions, too. Fix the problems and I wouldn't be surprised if it runs a lot slower than the scalar version due to all the locking. A better approach would be to sort chunks of the array in parallel and then merge them together.

Comment: Even if your [key] references don't result in full race conditions, they are likely to produce false sharing (where multiple threads access the same cache line, so it has to be evicted each time).  The first region, although there is no race, may not benefit from multi-threading.  Depending on the compiler, parallel may even disable simd optimization. If your compiler doesn't offer a non-temporal (cache bypass) store, a memset call (automatic substitution with some compilers), will accomplish it.   The C library memset() may be called directly by iso C binding, e.g. for gfortran.